# Comma in address field of CSV file

Tags: php

I have a CSV file which has a comma in the address field:

```
"Name", "Address"
"Jim","1234, Clinton St, 12345"
```

The code that I have used to escape the comma is:

```
//In a loop
$col[$x]=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $slice[$x]);
```

When I am inserting this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO table(Name,Address) VALUES('$col[0]','$col[1]')";
$stmte=$dbh->prepare($query);                   
$stmte->execute();
```

It tries to create three column in the database for the Address field.

Is there any workaround except for using regular expression? I am in a hurry to fix this and don't have time to explore regex concept.

Code:

```
if (($handle = fopen('./data/' . $filename, "r")) !== FALSE)
                {
            $fp = file('./data/' . $filename, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
            $rowCount = count($fp);
            $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                {
                $cnt++;
                $num = count($data);

                // echo $num;

                $result = $data;
                $str = implode(",", $result);
                $slice = explode(",", $str);

                // Insert into businesses
                // $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table',     'username', 'password');
                $col=array();

                $hostname="lh";
                $username="username";
                $password="password";

                $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=db", $username, $password);

                for ($x=0;$x<19;$x++)
                    $col[$x]=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $slice[$x]);



                $query = "INSERT INTO table(Name, Address, City, State,     Zipcode, Mailingaddress, Website, Email, Phone, Category, Membertype, Yearjoined,     Contactname, Contactemail, Notes, Memberdiscounts, Photo, Longitude, Latitude)
                             VALUES('$col[0]','$col[1]','$col[2]','$col[3]','$col[4]','$col[5]','$col[6]','$col[7]','$col    [8]','$col[9]','$col[10]','$col[11]','$col[12]','$col[13]','$col[14]','$col[15]','$col[16]',    '$col[17]','$col[18]')";

                $stmte=$dbh->prepare($query);

                $stmte->execute();
```

I have figured out what the problem is but not it's solution. According to me, the problem is that when the row is imploded, the output is comma separated values.

Found the solution. Just removed the implode/explode code and directly dealt with the $result data. Works good.

Comment: What is more important is _how are you creating `$col`_?

Comment: If you are not using `fgetcsv()` or [`str_getcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) you probably should be...  You cannot, for example `explode(',', $string)` to get CSV data..

Comment: I am using fgetcsv() to get data from csv. Code: $handle = fopen('./data/' . $filename, "r");$data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","); It is working fine for columns that don't have data with commas.

Comment: Please post that code then.  `fgetcsv()` will correctly parse that into 2 fields, if used properly.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `fgetcsv()` loop, and where all the relevant variables (like `$slice`) are set..

Comment: I have added the code now

Comment: There are quite a few problems and redundancies I see. I don't have time to flesh out an answer now, but hopefully someone can.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could even answer a bit now and elaborate later. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you implode and then explode instead of just using `$data`?

Comment: Thank! Yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of imploding and then exploding, simply do:

```
$slice = $data;
```

since `$data` is already an array of the csv columns.